# Html.OpenIdSelector in mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dotnetopenauth

I have the buttons rendering and here is the output:

```
<form action="/Auth/LogOnPostAssertion" method="post" target="_top">
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="M+ZFyksulpHW8asKultS/Y53gRs6eEli13rjL76+tc40ZB4WUbxAIpVMtsMnyGI2hXZ54DwyFypx/0UBlZqR+U7F/ALJRHiIGU9dCJpiohZHrlVEYZMgsF9HB14wruRia5A7jOidi4DlyfRriMjGrn63RMMJlLLHWIq5duSUiR4=" /><input
    id="ReturnUrl" name="ReturnUrl" type="hidden" value="" /><input id="openid_openidAuthData"
        name="openid_openidAuthData" type="hidden" value="" />
<div id="login-oauth-container">
    <ul class="OpenIdProviders">
        <li id="https://me.yahoo.com/" class="OPButton"><a href="#">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <img src="/Content/images/yahoo.gif" /><img src="http://www.google.com/" class="loginSuccess"
                        title="Authenticated as {0}" />
                </div>
                <div class="ui-widget-overlay">
                </div>
            </div>
        </a></li>
        <li id="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id" class="OPButton"><a href="#">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <img src="/Content/images/google.gif" /><img src="http://www.google.com/" class="loginSuccess"
                        title="Authenticated as {0}" />
                </div>
                <div class="ui-widget-overlay">
                </div>
            </div>
        </a></li>
        <li id="OpenIDButton" class="OpenIDButton"><a href="#">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <img src="/Content/images/openid.gif" /><img src="http://www.google.com/" class="loginSuccess"
                        title="Authenticated as {0}" />
                </div>
                <div class="ui-widget-overlay">
                </div>
            </div>
        </a></li>
    </ul>
    <div style='display: none' id='OpenIDForm'>
        <span class='OpenIdAjaxTextBox' style='display: inline-block; position: relative;
            font-size: 16px'>
            <input name='openid_identifier' id='openid_identifier' size='40' style='padding-left: 18px;
                border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: lightgray' />
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="helpDoc">
        <p>
            If you have logged in previously, click the same button you did last time.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

it has the webresource css too.

However, clicking on the buttons does nothing. on the nerddinner sample it obv pops up the login box for the provider you select.

what do i need to do to make this work? is there a checklist of things i need to be aware of?

Comment: Did you include the javascript file and do the init?

Comment: yeah - i spent aaaaaggggessssss on this :(